# defining a string in awk

Tags: awk

i have problem with awk,i want to define a string variable (str) depending on integer value NF to use it in another function:
if NF=3 
str="$1 $2 $3 ".

if NF=4 
str="$1 $2 $3 $4"....etc
how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you right, you want this?

```
kent$echo "a b c d"|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=s"$"i" ";print s}' 
$1 $2 $3 $4
```

Answer (score 0):

just use str=$0

if(NF==3) then str="$1 $2 $3"

if the line has 3 fields then obviously $0 is the combination of all the 3 fields.
And in case if you want the output Field  separator to be " " then just mention like OFS=" ".

example:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{str=$0;print str}' file
```

Comment: Your command doesn't substitute the field separators. You probably mean: `awk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{$1 = $1; print}'` or perhaps `awk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{$1 = $1; str = $0; print str}'`

Comment: i tried this code

            for(i=0;i<NF;i++)
            {
             str=str+"$"+i+" "
            }but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to see how to define and use variables , try this :

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
        print NF
        if (NF==3){
                str=$1 $2 $3 " says hello 3"
        }
        if (NF==2){
                str=$1 $2 
        }
        print str
}
```

Comment: NF value is changeable, i don't Know the value of NF, i tried this code

Comment: i tried this code for(i=0;i<NF;i++) { str=str+"$"+i+" " } but it does't work